# Cucumber with JUnit 5: features not found, tests aren't executed

Tags: cucumber, junit5

I'm using since a while Cucumber with JUnit 4 but currently I need to use it for the first time with JUnit 5 and it doesn't seem to work. I have the following dependencies:

```
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

I'm using the failsafe maven plugin configured as follows:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <groups>profileServer</groups>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The test class looks as follows:

```
@Cucumber
@Tag("profileServer")
public class CustomersCucumberIT
{
}
```

Here I'm using the @Tag annotation which is replacing JUnit4 @Category in order to selectively execute tests based on the  element configured in the failsafe maven plugin, here above.

The fetaures file is in src/main/test/resources/features/it and its name is customers.features.

Last but not least, here is the steps class:

```
@Tag("profileServer")
public class CustomersCucumberSteps
{
  ...
}
```

Running the verify goal display the following output:
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Share your Cucumber Report with your team at https://reports.cucumber.io    │
│ Activate publishing with one of the following:                              │
│                                                                             │
│ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    │
│ Environment variable:                      CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    │
│ JUnit:                                     @CucumberOptions(publish = true) │
│                                                                             │
│ More information at https://reports.cucumber.io/docs/cucumber-jvm           │
│                                                                             │
│ To disable this message, add cucumber.publish.quiet=true to                 │
│ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties                                      │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

but simply skips the test execution as if there weren't any. Previously, with JUnit 4 I was using @CucumberOptions in order to set the features location. But with JUnit 5 this annotation isn't supported any more and I don't find any other. It seems that it is supposed to be discovered.

I've seen a couple of posts mentioning that the features files might be configured in the failsafe or surefire maven plugin with:

```
...
<options>
  <configurationParameters>
    ...
  </configueationParameters>
</options>
...
```

but this syntax doesn't seem to be supported and, anyway, I didn't find any parameter that I could use in order to configure where the steps are.

Could someone please enlighten me on that and provide also a simple example ?

Many thanks in advance.

Seymour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. It appears that, as a matter of fact, Cucumber 6.7.0, that is used in my case, is unable to correctly interpret the JUnit 5 "@Tag" annotation. In the current test case presented above, commenting out the "groups" statement in the failsafe plugin configuration, which is used in order to filter the test execution, behaves as expected, i.e. all the tests are executed. Keeping this statement uncommented and whatever the "@Tag" annotation defines, all the tests are skipped.

However, JUnit 4 "@Category" annotation works as expected, i.e. the filtering is okay. Accordingly, in order to filter Cucumber tests execution based on, for example, maven profiles, only JUnit 4 style works.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/junit-platform-engine/src/main/java/io/cucumber/junit/platform/engine/Cucumber.java

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/junit-platform-engine

> Maven Surefire and Gradle do not yet support discovery of non-class based tests (see: gradle/#4773, SUREFIRE-1724).

> As a workaround you can use the `@Cucumber` annotation. Cucumber will scan the package of a class annotated with `@Cucumber` for feature files.

So if the runner class is `src/test/java/com/example/RunCucumberIT` then the feature files should be in `src/test/resources/com/example`.

Comment: Not sure what am I supposed to do with that as attaching links to the documentation hasn't ever been a pertinent answer. So, if you suggest the use of @Cucumber annotation, then you might want to read again the post you're replying to. Also, if you suggest that the steps and the IT class should be in the same package, then they already are.

Comment: I'm talking about the `.feature` files, not the step definitions. Cucumber will scan the package of a class annotated with `@Cucumber` for feature files.

Comment: Yeah, me too I was talking about the features, sorry. They are in a directory in the resource folder having the same path as the Java package containing the runner and the steps classes. And all tests are ignored as if they weren't there. It works as expected with JUnit 4 and @CucumberOptions.

Comment: Ah. Usually the thing people ommit from the question is the thing they got wrong. You didn't mention your directory layout so I assumed that was that problem. You may want to add it (the output of `tree` works very well on small projects).

Comment: And make sure to check/include the `target` folder.

Comment: There are at least three common mistakes in the project layout that result in features not being executed. You have made similar mistakes in the past. So you know it is not an unreasonable assumption. You didn't put in much effort to make the problem minimal and reproducible so it's also not unreasonable to assume the problem could be fundamental. Both assumptions were wrong and that seems to upset you unreasonably?

Comment: What is your reason to be condescending? 
Are you that daft ?